# What do Highlighted words indicate?

Tags: present-participles, adverbial-phrases

I don't understand why the writer highlights the following words in the given sentence:

> *"despite having to use an interpreter I was able to find out."*

The highlighted words are as follows:

- ***Despite*** and ***to use*** in green.
- ***having*** in yellow.

[image: screenshot of the highlighted sentence]

Comment: Can you provide more context? I can see no reason for the words being highlighted.

Comment: @LMS,......here is  more context ,now could u tell the reason behind highlighted words?(Despite having to use an interpreter I was able to find out.Here is the result of my interview with Je Wen- Siu.)

Comment: Some presentation like this is not helpful without a color key. Was such a key provided?

Comment: no,key is not provided...actually it is about some sort of grammatical reason (as it is the analysis of a book,published by a writer)which i am unable to recognize.

Comment: I found the sentence in this blog: http://theworldideas.blogspot.com/2011/08/chinas-way-to-progres-s-for-twenty-two.html It's filled with mistakes though, so I think it is an inaccurate transcription rather than the original source.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the comments above: without a key or the ability to read minds, it's hard to know exactly the thought process behind this.

However, it's worth noting that "despite" must match two elements. The second one is surprising in view of the first.

That first element is often a noun:

> Despite **our argument**, I think we mostly agree on this question.

But as a verb, it will be a gerund:

> Despite **disliking** fish, Jolene ate the entire meal her host served out of politeness.

In a compound tense, it's the auxiliary that will be a gerund:

> Despite **having** disliked fish all her life, Jolene ate all that cod without saying a word.

But what you notice is that what's bolded in this last one isn't what completes "despite" in a meaningful way. "Having" has nothing to do with fish either way; it's just the auxiliary, just part of the grammar. "Having" wouldn't stop one from enjoying a plate of cod. The relevant part is "disliked fish".

Hence, I might highlight "despite" and "disliked fish" in the same colour to remind a reader that "disliked fish" is the key element being contrasted with eating cod:

> **Despite** *having* **disliked fish** all her life, Jolene ate two servings and never complained, not once.

My best guess for the highlighting in the phrase you showed is an attempt to establish that connection between "despite" and "to use".

Anyway, it's not the most helpful breakdown of the sentence, particularly if the screen doesn't explain the colour key.